# How to code a message box vbyesno within an if statement to auto populate a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying all sorts of alternatives to coding a message box within my If statement in VBA excel but am getting no luck.

I have a userform with multiple text boxes for data entry. I'm trying to build a set of rules into a command button which is aimed at removing the experience/ knowledge out of the data capture activity.

based on the input in the first combobox (txt_Secondary_Reason) combined with a response from a message box/ subsequent comboboxes, I would like the following fields to be auto populated.

Please see code below:

```
`If txt_Secondary_Reason.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS" Then
ComboBox_Problem_Mode.Value = "PART NOT FITTED"
ComboBox_Problem_Mode_1.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS"
ComboBox_Root_Mode.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS"
ComboBox_Root_Cause.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS"

ElseIf txt_Secondary_Reason.Value = "BOM INCORRECT" And Response = 
MsgBox("Has QIR for this Non Conformance been raised?", vbYesNo + 
vbQuestion, "QIR?") Then
Select Case Response
Case Is = vbYes
    ComboBox_Problem_Mode_1.Value = "QIR RAISED"
    ComboBox_Problem_Mode.Value = "PART NOT FITTED"
    ComboBox_Root_Mode.Value = "NON CONFORMING"
    ComboBox_Root_Cause.Value = "BOM INCORRECT"

Case Is = vbNo
    ComboBox_Problem_Mode_1.Value = "QIR NOT RAISED"
    ComboBox_Problem_Mode.Value = "PART NOT FITTED"
    ComboBox_Root_Mode.Value = "NON CONFORMING"
    ComboBox_Root_Cause.Value = "BOM INCORRECT"
End Select
End If
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----`
```

"txt_Secondary_Reason" is a combobox, it initially was a textbox.

Based on the input here together with a textbox to ask the user if a certain condition has been satisfied , one out of two outcomes has to take effect and then move to next elseif...

Your kind assistance will be greatly appreciated

Regards
Zunaid

Answer (score 0):

The code would be like this

```
If txt_Secondary_Reason.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS" Then
    ComboBox_Problem_Mode.Value = "PART NOT FITTED"
    ComboBox_Problem_Mode_1.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS"
    ComboBox_Root_Mode.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS"
    ComboBox_Root_Cause.Value = "DON'T KNOW WHERE FITS"

ElseIf txt_Secondary_Reason.Value = "BOM INCORRECT" Then
    Response = MsgBox("Has QIR for this Non Conformance been raised?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "QIR?")
    Select Case Response
    Case Is = vbYes
        ComboBox_Problem_Mode_1.Value = "QIR RAISED"
        ComboBox_Problem_Mode.Value = "PART NOT FITTED"
        ComboBox_Root_Mode.Value = "NON CONFORMING"
        ComboBox_Root_Cause.Value = "BOM INCORRECT"

    Case Is = vbNo
        ComboBox_Problem_Mode_1.Value = "QIR NOT RAISED"
        ComboBox_Problem_Mode.Value = "PART NOT FITTED"
        ComboBox_Root_Mode.Value = "NON CONFORMING"
        ComboBox_Root_Cause.Value = "BOM INCORRECT"
    End Select
End If
```